# Entity Framework: Include Property depending on Subtype

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Main Model-Type called 'Organisation', which has multiple Subtypes. In Entity Framework, we save it via Table per Type appraoch.
Now, some Subtypes have also NavigationProperties to their relevant Information, which I would like to load, depending on the Type.
The problem: I can't define a concrete Organisation-Type DbSet, since I don't know this one at the time I'd have to.
So basically, I'd need to tell EF: If you load an Organisation of this Type, Include SubType1, if it is another Type, SubType2, etc.

If I do this tradionallty, EF moans because the Type "Organisation" doesn't know the Navigation-Properties of the Sub-Types.

Is there a possibility to combine the EF polymosphism with the possibility to include the specific Tables?

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your dbcontext and you can define any infomation in your subtype just ensure that you're using at least EF 6.0

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            //inhertance table per type 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Reponse>().ToTable("Organisation");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReponseChoix>().ToTable("Subtype1");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ReponseSimple>().ToTable("Subtype2");


        }
```